# OpenGL 2d drawing facing the user

Tags: opengl

I have an OpenGL scene in which the user can rotate the camera. I have some two dimensional shapes that I would like to always face the user. I do have the forward facing vector, and I do have the screen point at which the component should be drawn. I'm not sure the best way to approach this problem - should I be rotating the shape to the forward vector (which I'm not entirely sure how to do correctly)? Or is there another way I can just draw in two dimensions and ignore the rotation of the camera (maybe by using an orthographic projection)? Any sample code for helping with this would be appreciated.

PS - I'm doing this in Java, but the language is irrelevant here (it is just OpenGL specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered it in [Inverting rotation in 3D, to make an object always face the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467007/inverting-rotation-in-3d-to-make-an-object-always-face-the-camera/5487981#5487981)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the part of the example d = sqrt( xx² + yx² + zx² )? Everything else I understand...

Comment: The rotational part also contains any scaling done. If you'd set it to just identity, any scaling was lost. So we're determining the length of one of the rotation base vectors (any of the rotation base vectors would do) and use it to scale the identity to what has been applied before.

Comment: That makes sense. Though what is strange in my example is that I just printed out the modelview matrix and it is all 0, regardless of how I rotate the scene. I wouldn't expect that...I am using a 3rd party lib for much of the rendering though. I wonder if it is doing some other translations/rotations I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

My first though is to use the "gluLookAt" matrix.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

I would say, that you keep the position of the 2d objects, and then take the "eye" or camera position and set that as the target value for the 2d objects.  It should keep them facing the camera.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I move the camera to face the 2d objects? If that's the case, I cannot do that because that would affect other objects in the scene. Basically the 2d objects should always be facing forward, regardless of how the camera is facing the other objects in the scene.