# Negate rotation of a 3D 4x4 matrix

Tags: math, 3d, matrix

I have a billboard deep inside a 3D scene node hierarchy. The billboard inherits all 3D transformations applied to parent nodes.

I want the billboard to always "face the camera" (= have a zero derived rotation vector). The problem is that its derived matrix is read-only so I can't manipulate it directly to nullify rotation ([as proposed in another case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467007/inverting-rotation-in-3d-to-make-an-object-always-face-the-camera)).

What I **can** do is manipulate its **local matrix** so that the final derived matrix meets my requirements.

Is there a formula to achieve this?

Comment: You want to invert a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: No, let me rephrase : I have a 4x4 derived transformation matrix of a 3D node. I need to find a way to change the node's LOCAL transformation matrix so that the new resulted derived matrix will have zero rotations.

Comment: You have a 4x4 matrix, call it **A**. And you want to find a find another 4x4 matrix, call it **B**, such that **A** * **B** = **I**, the identity matrix?

Comment: @Beta : Heh, no. A 4x4 transformation matrix is "composed" of 3 "parts" : rotational, translation and scaling. I want to nullify the rotational part while maintaining the other 2 intact.

Comment: So the problem is to derive the rotational part?

Comment: Again : I know matrix A. I want matrix B where, A * B = C (or B * A = C? not sure) and C is A with the rotational part zeroed.

Comment: You're saying "I want to get C, where C is what I want". *Do you know the rotational part? Are you trying to find a way to derive it?*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17516/discussion-between-bill-kotsias-and-beta)

Comment: So long as you have not applied scaling, skew or perspective, the rotation part of the matrix will be the upper-left 3x3 portion. Feel free to replace it with an identity matrix or the rotation of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't use the homogeneous portion of the matrix, you can always do this.

A*B + B*A = C, where B = {0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0;0,0,0,1}

This should give you C = {0,0,0,s; 0,0,0,s; 0,0,0,s; x,y,z,2*w} where s is a scaling value and this is column oriented, meaning {1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,4} would be 4x2 matrix (4 rows two columns).

Hope this helps.