# Billboarding a 2D plane in 3D space where the camera is not the center of the scene

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, core-animation, scenekit

I am having an issue with transformations in an OpenGL / SceneKit / CoreAnimation environment. I have my scene of LEDs. I have also created a plane that intersects each LED. This plane will be transparent in the future and will be used to draw a highlight circle around the LED once I have the billboarding issue solved.

[Default Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r77cQ.png)

I am trying to make the planes billboard to the camera. The issue I am having is I can't find the exact kind of transformation to make this work in the kind of scene I have built.

In my mouseDragged: method I am inverting the X rotation and Y rotation matrices, Concatenating them and using that as the final transform to reverse the forward rotation of the LEDs to make it seem that the planes are always facing the camera.

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{

NSPoint winp    = [theEvent locationInWindow];
NSPoint p       = [sceneView convertPoint:winp fromView:nil];

mouseDraggedLocation = p;

//****************** TRANSFROM INIT ****************************************

CATransform3D localProjectionTransform;
CATransform3D translatedProjectionTransformX;
CATransform3D translatedProjectionTransformY;
CATransform3D translatedProjectionTransformFinal;

CATransform3D rotatedProjectionTransformX;
CATransform3D rotatedProjectionTransformY;
CATransform3D rotatedProjectionTransformFinal;

CATransform3D checkedProjectionTransform;
CATransform3D translatedProjectionTransformZ;
CATransform3D translationOnlyMatrix;


CATransform3D tempTransform;

//****************** TRANSFROM INIT ****************************************

// Figure out Angle

angleX = mouseDraggedLocation.x - mouseOldLocation.x;
angleY = mouseDraggedLocation.y - mouseOldLocation.y;

//********************************PLAYING WITH TRANSFORMS****************************




// X transform
rotatedProjectionTransformX = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleX * ROTATION_FACTOR, 0, 1, 0);
// Y transform
rotatedProjectionTransformY = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleY * ROTATION_FACTOR, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
rotatedProjectionTransformFinal = CATransform3DConcat(rotatedProjectionTransformX, rotatedProjectionTransformY);

translatedProjectionTransformX = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, angleX * ROTATION_FACTOR, 0);
translatedProjectionTransformY = CATransform3DMakeTranslation( -1 *(angleY * ROTATION_FACTOR), 0, 0);
translatedProjectionTransformFinal = CATransform3DConcat(translatedProjectionTransformX, translatedProjectionTransformY);

                       //                      rootNode
                       //                            |
                       //                     ledArrayNode
                       //                     /                    \
                      //     outlinePlaneNode (s)      LEDGeomNode(s)


// OH GOD PLEASE DON'T HATE ME FOR THIS, it chooses nodes that aren't Outline nodes, just disregard as crap test coding.

for (SCNNode *NodeTemp in [ledArrayNode childNodes]) {

    if ( [NodeTemp.name rangeOfString:@"O"].location == NSNotFound) {
        localProjectionTransform = NodeTemp.transform;
        NodeTemp.transform = CATransform3DConcat(localProjectionTransform, rotatedProjectionTransformFinal);
    } else {

    }



}


// This is what does the rotation with the outline planes, the previous loop did normal rotations for the LEDGeom Nodes

tempTransform = CATransform3DInvert(rotatedProjectionTransformFinal);

for (SPCLedGeom *LEDTemp1 in LED_Array) {
    localProjectionTransform = LEDTemp1.LED_Outline_Plane_Node.transform;


    LEDTemp1.LED_Outline_Plane_Node.transform = CATransform3DConcat(localProjectionTransform, tempTransform);
}




mouseOldLocation.x = mouseDraggedLocation.x;
mouseOldLocation.y = mouseDraggedLocation.y;


}
```

This generally works well for either axis by itself if I just lock the movement to either axis but not together,

[x-axis goofery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcaUI.png)

But when I move both axes, it looks like it takes about 2 full revolutions for the Y axis to catch "up" (also when moving in the Y axis the planes rotate along the x axis in a clockwise / counter clockwise motion), and then the x axis is "off" and won't move as it previously did.

When I was reading about [billboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467007/inverting-rotation-in-3d-to-make-an-object-always-face-the-camera), the jist was to pull the translation aspect from the rotation/transformation matrix and use that, however, in those examples, I think the camera was considered the center of the scene, whereas, in SceneKit and the way I am going about things, the center is the center of the LED array, and the camera is fixed while I am moving the LED nodes as you see in the mouseDragged: method.

Comment: So you want all the planes to always face to camera/point of view?

Comment: That's the plan. - Sorry for no update, I didn't setup my alerts correctly.

Comment: Have you looked at constraints?

Comment: I have not, I am going to dig into those soon here and report back. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Yes, [SCNConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Listings/Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2013_Sources_Slides_ASCSlideConstraints_m.html) is definitely the most straightforward answer! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward was to do it is using SCNConstraint [Here it is in the WWDC 2013 session.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Listings/Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2013_Sources_Slides_ASCSlideConstraints_m.html) You should download and take a look just to see it. In any event, you can use a constraint to keep the planes aimed at the camera. Since the planes will be transparent with very little actual visible to surround the LED. I think this is a pretty good choice.

```
nodeA.constraints = @[SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:nodeB];
```

In this case nodeB would be the cameraNode and nodeA would be the node containing all the planes.

Thank you [David Rönnqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608157/david-ronnqvist) For the arrow in the right direction.