# How can I set a flat plane to have the same rotation as the camera?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I would like to have a billboard of a tree to always face the camera.

[image]

Currently, I am just using `glRotatef()` and rotating the tree's yaw to the camera's yaw:

```
glRotatef(camera.yaw(), 0f, 1f, 0f);
```

However, that unfortunately does not work.

[image: <Insert GIF here (will add when it uploads)>]

It almost seems like the tree is turning to the right, when it should be turning left.

I've already tried inverting the rotation, but that doesn't work.

```
 glRotatef(-camera.yaw(), 0f, 1f, 0f);
OR
 glRotatef(camera.yaw(), 0f, -1f, 0f);
```

I could always resort to doing a crossed billboard (like I do on my grass), however scaling that up it looks horrible. I would prefer to only use it as a last resort.

[image]

I could also use a 3D model as an alternative, however I find that much harder, and it also is far more intensive on the graphics card.

[image]

I've already tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467007/inverting-rotation-in-3d-to-make-an-object-always-face-the-camera/5487981#5487981) for an answer, but not only is that confusing, but it is also for flash and really doesn't even seem to even get close on telling how to do it for other languages.

If needed (for whatever reason), my entire rendering code is:

```
public void render(){
    Main.TerrainDemo.shader.start();
    glPushMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glTranslatef(location.x * TerrainDemo.scale, location.y, location.z * TerrainDemo.scale); //Scale is the size of the map: More players online = bigger map.
    TexturedModel texturedModel = TerrainDemo.textModel;
    RawModel model = texturedModel.getRawModel();
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, TerrainDemo.textModel.getTexture().getID());
    glScalef(size.x, size.y, size.z);
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0.5f); //0,0,0, because of the shaders.
    glRotatef(Main.TerrainDemo.camera.yaw(), 0f, 1f, 0f);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
    Main.TerrainDemo.shader.stop();
}
```

`camera.yaw()`:

```
 /** @return the yaw of the camera in degrees */
public float yaw() {
    return yaw;
}
```

The yaw is in between 360 and -360.

```
 /** Processes mouse input and converts it in to camera movement. */
public void processMouse() {
    float mouseDX = Mouse.getDX() * 0.16f;
    float mouseDY = Mouse.getDY() * 0.16f;

    if (yaw + mouseDX >= 360) {
        yaw = yaw + mouseDX - 360;
    } else if (yaw + mouseDX < 0) {
        yaw = 360 - yaw + mouseDX;
    } else {
        yaw += mouseDX/50;
    }
    //Removed code relevant to pitch, since it is not relevant to this question.
}
```

UPDATE:
I have tried a lot of combinations, but the camera.yaw() does not seem to be remotely relevant to what the trees are doing?
No matter what I times or divide or seem to do with it, it always seems to be wrong!

Comment: It doesn't matter for which API the original question was asked, the mathematical principle is always the same. I admit that wrapping your mind around matrix math can be confusing in the beginning. I think your mental "roadblock" stems from the fact that you're using `glRotate` and its siblings; not only are these functions almost useless for anything serious, they're also deprecated and have been removed from modern OpenGL altogether. Matrices OTOH are easy, once you know how to work them. In the case of a billboard, what you want to do is, getting rid of any rotation relative to the camera.

Comment: And getting rid of the rotation is easiest done by setting the part of the modelview matrix, that does the rotation to identity (multiplied by a scale factor). Now in your particular case you actually want an axis aligned billboard; these are a bit tricker to set up.

Comment: One more piece of advice: Billboard are so past century. Except for things like vapour trails, beams of light and halos or HUD information overlaid over the scene there's no place for them in modern graphics. Use real geometry.

Comment: @datenwolf Are they so past century? Multiple games which can hit over 100,000 people on at once still use such techniques. Do you have a better suggestion about what I should use instead?

Comment: Something tells me that you just need to modify the angle slightly to get it to work: you want the billboard to be perpendicular to the camera forward vector in the XZ plane, which means that it should be the same angle + 90°. Have you tried to offset that rotation angle that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is an *axis aligned billboard*. First take the center axis in local coordinates, let's call it **a**. Second you need the axis from the point of view to *some* point along that axis (the tree's base will do just fine), let's call it **v**. Given these two vectors you want to form a "tripod" with one leg being coplanar with the center axis and the direction to viewpoint.

This can be done by orthogonalizing the vector **v** against **a** using the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), yielding **v'**. The third leg of the tripod is the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) between **a** and **v'** yielding **r** = **a** × **v'**. The edges of the axis aligned billboard are parallel to **a** and **r**; but this is just another way of saying, that a billboard is rotated into the (**a**,**r**) plane, which is exactly what rotation matrices describe. Assume the untransformed billboard geometry is in the XY plane, with **a** parallel to Y, then the rotation matrix would be

[**r**, **a**, (0,0,1)]

or in a slightly more elaborate way of writing it

```
| r.x , a.x , 0 |
| r.y , a.y , 0 |
| r.z , a.z , 1 |
```

To form a full 4×4 homogenous transformation matrix expand it to

```
| r.x , a.x , 0 , t.x |
| r.y , a.y , 0 , t.y |
| r.z , a.z , 1 , t.z |
|  0  ,  0  , 0 ,  1  |
```

where **t** is the translation.

---

Note that if anything about matrixes and vector operations doesn't yet make sense to you, you have to stop  anything you do with OpenGL right now, and first learn these essential basic skills. You will need them.

Comment: I don't learn about matrices because I can never find a good place to learn them. All I find are boring lectures that drone on, or books that presume I know **EVERYTHING** except the exact thing the book is trying to teach me. I don't learn matrices because I refuse to be bored out of my brain while doing it. Have you got any suggestions about that?

Comment: Even vectors can confuse me. For example, often people suddenly refer to a location as a "Vector"? I'm not wanting that specific one answered, but while I know a lot of the vector math, a lot of it can still confuse me because suddenly people keep referring to "Vectors" where I'm not using them or where I don't even know how they're used for a certain situation.

Comment: @Joehot200: There are certainly good tutorials about vector maths on the net, but if they still confuse you (and that's not a uncommon thing), perhaps you need something that describes it in a deeper way, with a more gradual approach, so that you get a better insight of how it works. I personally found the videos of the MIT course on linear algebra excellent. Try it out, and pick up a good textbook on the subject for exercises.

Comment: You couldn't just give some code, could you? I've been trying to work out this dammned answer for ages now, but it is simply too confusing (for example why I am using a value I have already got to calculate the same value? What are "Local coordinates"? etc?)

Comment: @Joehot200: I can't give you code, because that would require to know the overall structure of your program (or rather how the data is organized). Also there's no such thing as a "camera" in OpenGL; what you can do is "emulating" the effect a camera would have by applying the inverse transformation on the whole scene. But that doesn't help you with the billboard problem, because that requires you to keep track of the whole transformation chain (which your code may or may not do). Also what if I gave you the code? You'd slap it into your program, it may or may not work and you'd be not wiser.

Comment: @Joehot200: Trust me: It's far easier (in the long run) to understand how transformations, coordinate spaces and transformations work, rather than applying voodoo programming (which doesn't yield sustainable results anyway). This Computerphile video on matrices use in 3D graphics may give you some ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ60rFwh2ig